# Error trying to create dropdown list validation from defined name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I'm trying to create a data validation dropdown list from a defined name in Excel. It works fine on most sheets in the workbook and in a new sheet. But in one sheet where I need it I get the error:

```
The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?
```

For the Source field, I'm using a formula for the defined name with the list items:

```
=MyDefname
```

Again, this works fine to do exactly the same thing in other sheets and in a new sheet. In those cases the new dropdown works as expected, with list items drawn from the values in the cells in the defined name's range.

I checked the number formatting on the target cell of the problem sheet. It was text. I changed it to General, still got the same problem.

There is no sheet protection on any of the sheets. No workbook protection either.

What could be different about this sheet that prevents the dropdown list validation from working?

Comment: Hi @Greg Lovern. More details are needed in order to assess what may be going wrong. Ideally, providing a copy of the workbook would allow us to examine it and see if we can find any red flags.

Comment: @Greg Lovern, how many cells are in the defined name for the problem sheet?

Comment: @Brian this is for a work project, I'll have to copy out the problem to a new workbook with no sensitive corporate data.

Comment: @bugdrown the defined name with the list items is 5 cells, arranged vertically. All examples use the same defined name, both the ones that work fine and the one with the error.

Comment: @Greg Lovern Are the cells formulas? Or numbers?

Comment: @Greg Lovern Regardless, try pressing `F2` and `ENTER` on each cell. Sometimes reformatting text to general doesn't "take" unless you operate on the cell somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. It turned out there was a rogue, worksheet-scoped version of the defined name scoped to the problem sheet, and that version of the defined name was returning #REF!. I'm not sure how it got there. But once I deleted it, all was well.